# How to load paypal button component button twice from two different parent component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, rxjs, angular-services

am using PayPal component to load PayPal button in shared component so trying to access from two parent components, but unfortunately it shows the button in first component. If i tried with set timeout function then the button occurs twice as required. below is my code

Component 1:

```
   <app-paypal-component *ngIf="paypal"></app-paypal-component>
     component1.ts
      paypal= false;
     ngoninit(){
       setTimeout(()=>{
               this.paypal= true;
             this.cd.detectChanges();
     },5000)
    }
```

Component 2:

```
   <app-paypal-component ></app-paypal-component>
```

PaypalCompoent.ts:
Once the component is called first it triggers the load PayPal button method

```
async loadPaypalButton() {
    await this.paypalservice.injectPaypalBUTTONScript();
    cons id = '#test-pay-pal'
      const self = this;
        document
        .getWindow()
        .paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
            color: 'gold',
            label: 'paypal',
            height: 48,
            credit: false,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            fundingicons: 'true',
            tagline: false,
            size: 'responsive'
          },
          funding: {
          },
          createOrder() {
     
          },
          onApprove(data, actions) {
          
          },
          onError: (err) => {

          },
          onCancel: (cancelledData) => {

          }
        })
        .render(paypalId);
    }
  }
```

so here i want to achieve this with out set time out function which means i want to execute it in sequential order.is there any possibility to do with rxjs?

Comment: Assuming the query string parameters to it are the same in both cases, don't load the PayPal script twice on the same page. Load it exactly once.

Comment: @PrestonPHX i put condition to avoid mulitiple injections still issue is there